# Phaser Loader gets stuck on 99%

Tags: phaser-framework

Is there a limit to the number/size of assets I can run in a preload function?  I'm finding that often when loading the progress gets stuck at 99% and either takes a few minutes to complete and the completed event is fired or doesn't complete at all.

Is there anyway I can debug this to find out where the process is getting stuck, or is it simply that loading 250MB of game assets will crash the loader from time to time.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know that there's a hard cutoff or limit built into Phaser for the number or size of assets that can be loaded in the preload method. Since it sounds like you're sometimes seeing a delayed-but-successful completion while other times you never reach 100% successful load, it's more likely that you're hitting a timeout or some other load error.

You should be able to catch these errors with the [FILE_LOAD_ERROR](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Loader.Events.html#event:FILE_LOAD_ERROR) event:

```
preload() {
   // Preload setup
   
   this.load.on('loaderror', this.onLoadError);
} 

onLoadError(file) {
  console.log(file);
}
```

Another option you might explore is modifying the [LoaderConfig](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Types.Core.html#.LoaderConfig).

With that being said, 250MB before you do anything seems like a huge lift. You might want to consider breaking up the load across scenes, verifying that your assets are as compressed as possible or doing some lazy loading of assets when needed instead of in the preload. You can see an example of an on-demand asset load [here](http://labs.phaser.io/edit.html?src=src/loader%5Cimage%5Cload%20image%20on%20click.js).

Comment: I will try some of these suggestions.  I guess in my mind I just wanted to load everything before people start and then it's done.  In reality I can spread the load over some of the scenes.  I've worked out it is video files that cause the most issues, removing them makes the game load a lot more consistently.